# WCF - Connecting to NHibernate via different project

Tags: .net, wcf, nhibernate

I have a solution which has two projects. Lets just assume Project A & B. Project A is a ASP.Net web application and it uses NHibernate. Project B is a WCF service and i would like to use the database through project A with its already written NHibernate services.

I want to know if this is possible? If what are the steps to follow and add to get it working?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would recommend looking into the possibility of refactoring out the common database functionality into a Project C. Project A and project B would then depend on Project C (the nHibernate/data project).
There may be some configuration that needs to be duplicated. E.g. your current ASP .Net web application may have some nHibernate related settings which need to be duplicated in your WCF service project.

Comment: Yes you got my point. Data access layer is being isolated from project A & B. I would like to know what configurations files should i add in Project B (WCF) to connect to my data access layer?